# How to store raw values for all properties?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I store raw values for all properties in elasticsearch ?

I need raw values for aggregation, properties are not known a-priory.

**Update:**

Want all properties be

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "fields": { 
        "raw": { 
            "type": "string", 
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    } 
}
```

Whereas properties are dynamic

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to use PUT method to add data to elasticsearch. 

Example: 

`$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/products/product/123' -d '{
  "ProductID": 123,
  "SellingPrice": 1200.00,
  "DiscountAmount":0.00,
  "Discount": {
    "Type": "percentage",
    "Amount": 25,
    "StartDate": "2014-08-13T12:05:00",
    "EndDate": "2014-12-31T12:10:00"
  }
}'`

CURL library can be used to send data to your elasticsearch. For testing purpose you can use [chrome sense plugin][1]. 

For getting aggregation use POST or GET method. 

Example:

`$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/products/product/_search?search_type=count' -d '{
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "SellingPrice"
      }
    }
  }
}
'`

Above example will return aggregation result as below:

 `{
   "took": 48,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 117,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "my_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 1200,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}`



  [1]: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i know how to add data, but problem is i want to store non analyzed data too

Comment: Use mapping as follow:

` "Name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "store": true,
                  "index_analyzer": "index_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer",
                  "fields": {
                     "original": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }``

you can search 'not analysed field' like "Name.original"

Comment: i don't know names of fields

Comment: Its example field name...  before indexing your data.. you can map your field name like this.. here Name field is analysed and Name.original is not analysed.

Comment: yes but i downt know what the name of the fields would be

Comment: i want this for all the fields

Comment: i want this for all fields not knowing their names. Fields are dinamic

Comment: "properties are not known a-priory"

Comment: elasticsearch accepts only JSON format.. default string is "not analysed field" only. However if you are passing new value to elasticsearch automatically created the mapping field for that based on datatype

Comment: i want all the properties to have {
   "type": "string",
   "fields": { 
        "raw": { 
            "type": "string", 
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    } 
}

Comment: and i don't know what properties my JSONs wold have. How to do this ?

Comment: JSONs would have different properties

Answer (score 0):

found solution

```
curl -X PUT /index

{
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "default": {
                    "match": "*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}